# illogical issue in a sparql query with Virtuoso

Tags: java, jersey, sparql, virtuoso

After hours of debugging I am writing here..
The following code does not

```
public String search(@QueryParam("query") String search_string, @QueryParam("match_type") @DefaultValue("") String match_type, @QueryParam("terminology") @DefaultValue("") List<String> terminology_list)
    throws ServletException, IOException 
{

    VirtGraph set = new VirtGraph (hostURL, userName, password);
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    search_string = search_string.replaceAll(java.util.regex.Pattern.quote(" "), " and ") ;
    String text="";

    for(String term_items:terminology_list) {
        if(!match_type.equals("exact")) {
            text="select ?uri, ?label where { " +
                "quad map virtrdf:DefaultQuadMap " +
                "{ graph ?g { ?uri ?p ?label . ?label bif:contains '" + 
                search_string + 
                "' option ( score ?sc ) . }}} " +
                "order by desc ( ?sc * 3e-1 + sql:rnk_scale ( <LONG::IRI_RANK> ( ?uri ) ) ) limit 20 offset 0";
        }
        else if(match_type.equals("exact")) {
            text="select ?uri, ?label where { quad map virtrdf:DefaultQuadMap { graph <"
    +term_items+"> { ?uri ?p ?label.FILTER (?label = '"+search_string+"'@en) .}}}";
        }

        VirtuosoQueryExecution vqe = VirtuosoQueryExecutionFactory.create(text, set);

        ResultSet results = vqe.execSelect();
        ResultSetFormatter.outputAsJSON(out, results);
    }

    return out.toString();
}
```

The problem occurs in the `else if` statement as the result set at the end of the execution is empty no matter how many items from the list I declare in the link. 
For example if in the link I would type **&terminology=test** this is converted to:

```
 text="select ?uri, ?label where { quad map virtrdf:DefaultQuadMap { graph <**test**> { ?uri ?p ?label.FILTER (?label = '"+search_string+"'@en) .}}}";
```

Funnily, running that sparql query on an end point does actually return results. Only while running it in eclipse, it does not !

One can also not say that there is any error further in the code after the `else` statement because the same code is used for the `if`statement and it is running properly..

Comment: "The following code does not".  Does not what?